# Testing for circular uniformity of headings (Rayleigh, v-test)

Tags: statistical-significance, biostatistics, uniform-distribution, circular-statistics

I have two-dimensional recordings of animal trajectories. The animals exit their nest and I am trying to test whether their headings over a period of time have a distribution different than uniform. My question is do the animals search around the nest randomly or they tend to go towards a particular direction? I found about the Rayleigh and V-test of circular uniformity. Since I have an expected direction where the animals should be trying to go I decided to use the V-test (but I am not fussy about that). I now have two options and I am wondering which one is the most appropriate. One option is to segment the trajectories into segments of equal length, calculate the heading along each segment, put all the segment headings together in a list, and use the V-test (or the Rayleigh test) to test for circular uniformity of these headings. The other option is to calculate the mean resultant vector (r) of each trajectory and use these mean headings (one mean heading per trajectory, n=16) as the data to calculate the V-test (or Rayleigh test) on. I am not certain which of the two options is the right thing to do.

I am concerned because someone told me that the above tests assume the headings are independent, which is clearly not the case if I use the headings along segments of a trajectory. However, looking at the original V-test paper (Durand D, Greenwood JA (1958) Modifications of the Rayleigh test for uniformity in analysis of two-dimensional orientation data. J Geol 66:229–238) as well as elsewhere I don't see any mention about such an independence assumption. Any suggestions?

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the original paper; there are earlier works by those two authors that discuss V. Confusingly there's another test for circular uniformity that's also called the V-test (Kuiper's test).

Comment: I see, that's confusing. I have tried the [CircStats Matlab toolbox](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10676-circular-statistics-toolbox-directional-statistics) and the [Astropy python library](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.stats.circstats.vtest.html) implementation ( [code here](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/_modules/astropy/stats/circstats.html) ). I could use the Rayleigh test if needed but I still have the same concern about independence. Any opinion on that?

Comment: I think they all assume independence but I haven't been through the papers yet

Comment: From looking at one of the earlier Durand and Greenwood references (J. A. Greenwood and D. Durand, (1955) “The distribution of length and components of the sum of n random unit vectors,” Ann. Math. Statist., vol. 26, no. 2, pp. 233–246), it seems clear that the test assumes independence.

Comment: Thank you Glen.